# Building a picketlink app

Tags: java, jboss, picketlink

I like to build (mvn clean install) the picketlink example on
https://github.com/picketlink/TODO
But it wont work because the dependency picketlink-extension 3.0.0 isnt available in any repository.
Can anyone give me a hint what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to change

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.picketlink.extensions</groupId>
    <artifactId>picketlink-extensions-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

to

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.picketlink.extensions</groupId>
    <artifactId>picketlink-extensions-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-2013Feb08</version>
</dependency>
```

or anything newer from [Maven Repository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.picketlink.extensions/picketlink-extensions-core)